# PHP mysqli_connect() error

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to open up a MySQL connection using this code (using the actual parameters in my real code)

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("hostname","user","password","db");
```

and I got this error:

> Host 'hostname' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'

I've also tried to use the SQL command "FLUSH HOSTS" in phpMyAdmin, but I don't have the privileges to do it. Are there any thoughts as to what this could be?

Comment: I guess too many connections. But that is just a hunsh

Comment: It tells you how to solve it. " unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'"

Comment: make connection like that  $con=new mysqli(("localhost","root","password","db"); and use localhost instead of hostname if your mysql at same machine

Comment: Did you mean to post this to DBA.SE instead?

Answer (score 1):

After connecting to your database, make sure you always close your connection using:

```
$mysqli->close();
```

From your query browser (such as phpMyAdmin), enter the command: `FLUSH HOSTS;` as [explained here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html).